# how do I get DBeaver to show a Save button?

Tags: dbeaver

I want a save button that I can click with the mouse, but when I focus on a SQL editor page and file and do >Window >Customise Perspective >Edit actions, it's greyed out and says "Save (Ctrl+S' command cannot be made visible in this dialog.
DBeaver Community v6.0.5.2019... Windows 10 Enterprise 2016

It's just a simple thing so I don't have to keep switching between keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some months old so it may not be relevant for you, but this may help others (I was brought here as the lone google search result and had to keep poking around until I found it)

anyway, in DBeaver menu select Window>Preferences>DBeaver>Editors there should be a checkbox for 'Show Edit toolbar'. Check that and apply and close. Exit and restart DBeaver and it should have buttons for save/undo/etc. If it still does not, go to Window>Customize Perspective and the 'Edit actions' toolbar items should no longer be unselectable so you should be able to add them to the toolbar from there.